# iTextSharp, add barcode to page 1 after generating document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am using iTextSharp (5.5.5.90) to generate PDF files. I am using paragraphs and importing pages from readers and such. Here is how I create my document, from there I just append what I need:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("filename.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.LETTER), 58, 58, 100, 50);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
```

Once the file is created, I add paragraphs like this:

```
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Paragraph text"));
```

And import pages from readers like this:

```
writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page), 0, 0);
```

My question is how would I go back to page one after generating the entire document and add an element to page one? I will be adding a barcode (I know how to add barcodes, tables and such where I want them on the current page), but I don't know how to "go back" to page one to add an element.

Here is the full code, but you won't be able to compile it because of dependencies. Also, don't get caught up in the details of the full code, as this is a large project to create dynamically generated documents. https://pastebin.com/kABi7fzW

Comment: Given that you're generating the document from the get go, is there a reason why you're not inserting the barcode at the start?

Comment: DiskJunky, I don't know the entire length of the document until the end. The barcode contains the number of pages in the document. Because of the paragraphs and the way they'll automatically flow into the next page when they reach the bottom, I can't be 100% sure how many pages there are (shy of counting chars/lines/etc early on, which I wanted to avoid)

Comment: you're going to have to put in a placeholder at the very least at the start for the barcode or the mere insertion could push out your page count. In this case, you need to create the document, reopen it, find the barcode placeholder and updated it. It's a more involved process

Comment: The barcode will be laid on top of the other paragraphs, so it won't modify the length (untested but i think this will work). 

Yes, option B is for sure saving, reopening and adding the barcode. Is there a way to place something to reference back to? I can put the "table" where I want it and add data later if that is possible.

Comment: You can create a `PdfTemplate` and add it to the first page. When you are finished, you can draw the barcode onto that template.

Comment: mkl, I will look into this. Thank you. This sounds like what I was hoping to find originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't attest as to the exactly calls to `iTextSharp`'s as we approached our documentation quite differently; open a Word template, at the data as `DataTables`, etc., do a MailMerge, close and reopen and save as PDF. Sounds more involved but doesn't require the granular level of detail you're doing of creating the document paragraph by paragraph but it does allow the document generator to worry about content and not style placement (handled via Word, manually and external to the application).

From experience with `iTextSharp`, you'll have a lot of trouble trying to float an element on top of a section to insert the barcode. The document generation tool has an annoying tendency to not *quite* work in this scenario. We endured many weeks of back and forth with iTextSharp support and a version upgrade and still couldn't get it to behave properly in all scenarios.

As discussed in the comments and given how you've already written your code (I doubt you'll scrap all that code and start with a MailMerge unless you really, really have to), you'll need to insert a placeholder block that you can locate via `iTextSharp`'s `PdfBuilder` api. I'd imagine that setting a bookmark location would likely be the easiest way.

If it's possible (preferable?) to have the barcode on a page of its own, then you already have the code needed to do this (circa line `324` in your pastebin link) with;

```
// create doc...
// reopen doc and get page count
doc.NewPage();
// add barcode with page count + 1
// save
```

Comment: I am actually moving from Mail Merge to this new system, because we want to be able to define paragraphs that go with each form that gets enclosed, vs. having to generate multiple cover pages if there are multiple forms (or combination cover pages, which is what we have now and its becoming too difficult to maintain). I'm using a database system to store the content and forms relationships, and then generating the documents based on the requests from the staff.

Comment: I ended up choosing the option to close/reopen the document and add it there, as it is the least intensive on me and since this runs as an automated process, I'm not too concerned about run-time. Thank you for your suggestions. I will continue to monitor this for future suggestions also.

Comment: What was your JIRA issue ID? I would like to check why we weren't able to answer your question in the best possible way.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, it was a few years ago now so I'd have to go digging. In our scenario, we had a template and were trying to insert images, pdfs and docs into a larger, compiled document with a ToC. The mix of images/docs proved to be the pain point in getting formatting and placing correct. Floating the inserted items caused a lot of tweaking which one of the support team found a way around.